# image tiling in loops using Python OpenCV

Tags: python, image, loops, opencv, tiling

Python noob needs some help guys! Can someone show me how to rewrite my code using loops? Tried some different syntaxes but did not seem to work!

```
img = cv2.imread("C://Users//user//Desktop//research//images//Underwater_Caustics//set1//set1_color_0001.png")

    tile11=img[1:640, 1:360]
    cv2.imwrite('tile11_underwater_caustic_set1_0001.png', tile11)

    tile12=img[641:1280, 1:360]
    cv2.imwrite('tile12_underwater_caustic_set1_0001.png', tile12)

    tile13=img[1281:1920, 1:360]
    cv2.imwrite('tile13_underwater_caustic_set1_0001.png', tile13)

    tile21=img[1:640, 361:720]
    cv2.imwrite('tile21_underwater_caustic_set1_0001.png', tile21)

    tile22=img[641:1280, 361:720]
    cv2.imwrite('tile22_underwater_caustic_set1_0001.png', tile22)

    tile23=img[1281:1920, 361:720]
    cv2.imwrite('tile23_underwater_caustic_set1_0001.png', tile23)

    tile31=img[1:640, 721:1080]
    cv2.imwrite('tile31_underwater_caustic_set1_0001.png', tile31)

    tile32=img[641:1280, 721:1080]
    cv2.imwrite('tile32_underwater_caustic_set1_0001.png', tile32)

    tile33=img[1281:1920, 721:1080]
    cv2.imwrite('tile33_underwater_caustic_set1_0001.png', tile33)
```

As you can see, the image will be cut into 9 equal-size pieces, how to write it using loops?

Comment: Show us what "syntaxes" you have tried.

Answer (score 3):

This won't produce the same result like your code, but will give you some ideas:

```
img = cv2.imread('sample.jpg')
numrows, numcols = 4, 4
height = int(img.shape[0] / numrows)
width = int(img.shape[1] / numcols)
for row in range(numrows):
    for col in range(numcols):
        y0 = row * height
        y1 = y0 + height
        x0 = col * width
        x1 = x0 + width
        cv2.imwrite('tile_%d%d.jpg' % (row, col), img[y0:y1, x0:x1])
```

Answer (score 2):

I needed image tiling where last parts or edge tiles are required to be full tile images.

Here is the code I use:

```
import cv2
import math
import os

Path = "FullImage.tif";
filename, file_extension = os.path.splitext(Path)
image = cv2.imread(Path, 0)

tileSizeX = 256;
tileSizeY = 256;
numTilesX = math.ceil(image.shape[1]/tileSizeX)
numTilesY = math.ceil(image.shape[0]/tileSizeY)

makeLastPartFull = True; # in case you need even siez

for nTileX in range(numTilesX):
    for nTileY in range(numTilesY):
        startX = nTileX*tileSizeX
        endX = startX + tileSizeX
        startY = nTileY*tileSizeY
        endY = startY + tileSizeY;

        if(endY > image.shape[0]):
            endY = image.shape[0]

        if(endX > image.shape[1]):
            endX = image.shape[1]

        if( makeLastPartFull == True and (nTileX == numTilesX-1 or nTileY == numTilesY-1) ):
            startX = endX - tileSizeX
            startY = endY - tileSizeY

        currentTile = image[startY:endY, startX:endX]
        cv2.imwrite(filename + '_%d_%d' % (nTileY, nTileX)  + file_extension, currentTile)
```

Comment: For anyone else wanting to use this for colour images change image = cv2.imread(Path, 0) to image = cv2.imread(Path, 1)

Answer (score 0):

This is for massive image reconstruction using part of flowfree his code. By using a folder of sliced images in the same area the script is, you can rebuild the image.  I hope this helps.

```
import cv2
import glob
import os

dir = "." 

pathname = os.path.join(dir, "*" + ".png")
images = [cv2.imread(img) for img in glob.glob(pathname)]

img = images[0]

numrows, numcols = 1,1
height = int(img.shape[0] / numrows)
width = int(img.shape[1] / numcols)


for row in range(numrows):
    for col in range(numcols):
        y0 = row * height
        y1 = y0 + height
        x0 = col * width
        x1 = x0 + width
        cv2.imwrite('merged_img_%d%d.jpg' % (row, col), img[y0:y1, x0:x1])
```